# ORA-01722 invalid number but the value is not a number

Tags: oracle, jdbctemplate, ora-01722

I'm trying to insert something in an Oracle DB and I get :
ORA-01722 invalid number

I understand that this happens when Oracle tries to convert String to a Number and fails.
I've read a number of similar questions but none really helped me.

I've managed to locate the field which is creating the problem and it's value is:

It's being updated using a batchUpdate method of `org.springframework.jdbc.code.JdbcTemplate`, and it's being inserted with a line: `ps.setString(22, item.getDzvalue())`

item.getDzvalue is `DZ40209000`, but the field it's being set to is NCHAR(60).

Why is any number conversion taking place? I'm a bit confused, but as I understand NCHAR should be able to take this value in the column.

Comment: Show us the complete SQL statement. **[edit]** your question. Do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I would guess the order you're supplying the values doesn't match the column order in the table or the column list in the insert, so you aren't inserting that string into the column you think. Or it isn't that column/value that's a problem at all. But it can only be a guess without seeing the code.